# Arg cannot be resolved when using defresource

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, ring, liberator

I'm trying to use liberator macro `defresource` but the intellij IDE keeps returning the error "(arg) cannot be resolved"

I'm doing a project using clojure, ring and liberator, in this project i have the dependecies as

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
                 [liberator "0.15.3"]
                 [compojure "1.6.0"]
                 [ring/ring-core "1.7.1"]]
```

in the code

```
(:require [liberator.core :refer [defresource resource]]
           [ring.middleware.params :refer [wrap-params]]
           [compojure.core :refer [defroutes ANY]]))
(defresource ok
             :available-media-types ["text/html"]
             :handle-ok "This is iia")
(defroutes app
           (ANY "/test" [] ok))
(def handler
  (-> app
      wrap-params))
```

when using `defresource ok` the message "ok cannot be resolved" keeps showing

Comment: What do you mean by "intellij IDE keeps returning the error"?  Is this a specific problem inside intellij?  When do you get it etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Cursive, you should be able to tell IntelliJ to treat `defresource` as a `def`.

See Cursive's macro [docs](https://cursive-ide.com/userguide/macros.html).

Comment: Could you please add what fixed your problem from that link or some gist of it?

Comment: It should be `Resolve liberator.core/defresource as def`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using `IntelliJ+Cursive`:

1. Put cursor at `defresource`.
2. `Alt+Enter` on keyboard (or `Show Context Actions` from popup menu).
3. You should see popup menu with two items, click `Resolve liberator.core/defresource as...`.
4. You should see some suggestions, click `defn`.

After that IntelliJ should treat all `defresource` in the code as `defn` and related warnings should disappear.